# properties of planar graph with f edges

Tags: graph-theory

I am having trouble with the following question:

given a simple planar graph G=(V,E) with f edges, in which the length of each circle is at least 6.

those are the questions i couldn't solve from the book:

a)prove that $|E| \geq 3f$

b)prove that $|E| \leq 1.5*|V|-3$

c)prove that an interesection with rank less than 3 can exist in G

I tried to use eulers formula and ($|E| = |V|+f-2$) and its driven applications, but i cannot happen to get a proof for those given 3 questions. i succeed doing the other exercises in the question though. please help me if you can.

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For planar graphs $f$ usually denotes the number of faces, not edges.

a) Double count the number $N$ of pairs $(e, \alpha)$ where an edge $e$ belongs to a face $\alpha $. Since each edge belongs to at most two faces, $N\le 2|E|$. On the other hand, as I understood, each face has at least $6$ edges, so $N\ge 6|F|$. Thus $|E|\le 3|F|$.

b) By Euler’s formula, $6-3|V|+3|E|=3|F|$. Applying (a), we obtain $6-3|V|+3|E|\ge |E|$, that is  $2|E|\ge 1.5|V|-3$.

c) I didn’t understand the formulation.

Comment: thank you very much. 

in 3) i was required to show that there exists in G an ineresection whose rank is less than 3.

Comment: @BeginningMath I don't know what is an intersection in a graph and what is its rank.